# dumping DB in mysql

Tags: mysql

when I run below statement, mysql is complaining having error.

```
mysqldump --triggers --routines -u root -p mydb > mydb_20120924.dmp;
```

mysql version: 5.1.34

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'mysqldump --triggers --routines -u root -p mydb > mydb_20120924.dmp' at line 1

Comment: can you complate your question by putting error message shown?

Comment: please check with out --triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the mysqldump command from inside the mysql command line interpreter.

Does the prompt for the mysqldump command say 'mysql> '? Then you are running the mysql command line interpreter. It should be used - indeed, it can only be used - for running mysql commands.

mysqldump is a separate command and must be run from the shell.

Quit mysql by typing "exit" - you will see a shell prompt. Then the mysqldump command will work.

Comment: yah. correct. I just didn't notice that until one of my friends notice d and told me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database called "mydb" this should work. You could try using --database specifically:

> mysqldump --triggers --routines -u root -p --database mydb >
>   mydb_20120924.dmp;

Comment: same. is this related with privileges?

Comment: There's no reason why it would be necessary to add --database explicitly - that wasn't the problem.